# I want to generate some mathematical questions by using rand and function

Tags: c++, random, mathematical-expressions

I am learning c++ program in my home. So I am not good at using it.

1. First I want to output the programme like the below statement.
2. "Question 1: 4 + 5 = 9 correct!
3. "Question 2: 5 * 5 = 9 fail!
4. "Question 3: 9 - 5 = 4  correct!
   I want to produce the question at least 5 and not more than 10 questions.
   My curiosity is that how can I increase the question number and how can I check that whether I answer this question correct or not. This is so far I'm done. Please do understand my code because I am learning C++ alone in my home

---

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, digit1, digit2,;
    char op, k;
    a = digit1;
    b = digit2;
    op = k;

    srand (time (NULL));

    generate2Digits(a,b);
    generateOperators(op);


}

void generate2Digits (int& a, int& b) 
{
    int digit1;
    int digit2;

    srand (time (NULL));

    digit1= rand ()%10;
    digit2= rand ()%10;

    for(int i = 1; i<= rand()%10; i++) 
    {
        cout << digit1 << endl;
        cout << digit2<< endl;
    }


}

void generateOperators(char& op)

{ 
    int k;

    for(int i=1; i<= 10; i++)
    {
        k = rand () % 4;

        switch(k)
        {
            case 0: cout << "+" << endl;
            break;
            case 1: cout << "-" << endl;
            break;
            case 2: cout << "*" << endl;
            break;
        }

    }


}

void printExpression(int a, int b, char op)
{
    do
    {






    }
}
```

// how to print the question expression like the above example?
 // how to check the whether the answer is correct or not?

Comment: Needs reformatting...

Comment: @Steve ... and better explanation I would say.

Comment: how can I increase the question number and how can I check that whether I answer this question correct or not.

Comment: What's going on in `printExpression()`?

Comment: generateOperators() sets k to a value from 0 to 3 inclusive, but the switch has no `case 3:` Either change that to `% 3` or add another case for division.

Answer (score 2):

In `generate2Digits()`, you are generating and printing the numbers 10 times via a loop right away.

I think you should just find the numbers and wait till you find the operator.

Since you got functions to generate digits (`generate2Digits()`) and operand (`generateOperators()`), you could write a loop to repeat n times (where n is the number of questions) and call the functions in each iteration of the loop.

Let's modify `generate2Digits()` to

```
void generate2Digits (int& a, int& b)
{
    a=rand()%10;
    b=rand()%10;
}
```

`a` and `b` are passed by reference and changes made here will be reflected back to the actual arguments.

In this function, we just find 2 values and store them in `a` and `b`.

Now

```
int generateOperators(char& op, int a, int b)
{
    int k = rand () % 3;
    switch(k)
    {
        case 0: op='+';
            return a+b;
        case 1: op='-';
            return a-b;
        case 2: op='*';
            return a*b;
    }
}
```

In your program you used `k = rand () % 4` but didn't have a `case` for `3`. Since you don't have such a case, you may use `k = rand () % 3;`.

An operand is given to `op` and to make things easier, the values of `a` and `b` are also available here and based on the chosen operator, the correct answer is also calculated and returned. Here I return this value and make the return type `int` instead of `void`. You could use a parameter passed by reference if you like.

I didn't use `break`s inside the `switch` here because `return` will take the control out of the case anyway.

Now

```
void printExpression(int n)
{
    int a, b, ans, res;
    char op;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        generate2Digits(a, b);
        res=generateOperators(op, a, b);
        cout<<a<<op<<b<<"=";
        cin>>ans;
        if(ans==res)
        {
            cout<<" correct!";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<" fail!";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Make a loop to iterate `n` times where `n` may be the number of questions. On each iteration, the 2 numbers are found using `generate2Digits()` and operand and correct answer is found with `generateOperators()`.

The use enters a number as answer and if this answer is same as the value calculated by `generateOperands()` here, the answer is correct.

You need to use the `srand()` only once and before the first `rand()` in here. The one in `main()` is enough. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343853/5375464).

I see that you don't consider division. If you need that you must be using floating point type like `double` instead of `int`.

Comment: Hi I really appreciate what you are done for me! But I want to use another function such as int result(a,b,op), so that I can check result there!

Comment: @hoi You can do what's done in the last part of `printExpression()` in that function then

Comment: do you know how to count the number that is correct?

Comment: use that function to calculate and return the result, then match it to the user input.

if its correct, increment a counter.